# Why is twitter boostrap not working on my laravel 5 project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and I can seem to figure out why twitter bootstrap is not working. Below is the code fragment.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link href="http://localhost:8000/css/boostrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>     
    <div class="container">
        <!-- row 1 -->
        <header class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/logo.png" alt="Wisdom Pets. click for home."></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-7">
                <img src="http://localhost:8000/img/animals.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </header>        
        <!-- row 2 -->
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Why is boostrap not working?</h1>      
            <p>Appreciate any explanation</p>
        </div>    
        <!-- row 3 -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/gsd.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>Thanks for helping our German Shepherd</h4>
                <p>During the summer, my German Shorthair Pointer, Tonto, began to have severe redness and itching on his belly and feet.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/kitten.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>Our diabetic kitty is better</h4>
                <p>When Samantha, our sweet kitten, began sleeping all the time and urinating excessively, we brought her to see the specialists at Wisdom.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/bulldog.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>Our grape-loving dog</h4>
                <p>The staff at Wisdom worked tirelessly to determine why our three-year old bulldog, Roxie, started going into sudden kidney failure.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/goldfish.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>A dog antibiotic cured our fish</h4>
                <p>Wisdom Pet Medicine is the only clinic around that will even book pet fish for appointments.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All the various javascripts and CSS files are properly loaded. Bootstrap is not taking effect. All the columns within the different rows are just stacked vertically irrespective of screen size.

Comment: What's not working, what is the issue?

Comment: Hello @nathanmac bootstrap is not working. I have improved the question. All my columns are just stacked vertically just like a normal <div> does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> boostrap.min.css

sure about name?

anyway you can "link" css and js with Bootstrap CDN to test

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
        <!-- row 1 -->
        <header class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/logo.png" alt="Wisdom Pets. click for home."></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-7">
                <img src="http://localhost:8000/img/animals.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </header>        
        <!-- row 2 -->
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Why is boostrap not working?</h1>      
            <p>Appreciate any explanation</p>
        </div>    
        <!-- row 3 -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/gsd.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>Thanks for helping our German Shepherd</h4>
                <p>During the summer, my German Shorthair Pointer, Tonto, began to have severe redness and itching on his belly and feet.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/kitten.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>Our diabetic kitty is better</h4>
                <p>When Samantha, our sweet kitten, began sleeping all the time and urinating excessively, we brought her to see the specialists at Wisdom.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/bulldog.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>Our grape-loving dog</h4>
                <p>The staff at Wisdom worked tirelessly to determine why our three-year old bulldog, Roxie, started going into sudden kidney failure.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                <p><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/goldfish.jpg" alt=""></p>
                <h4>A dog antibiotic cured our fish</h4>
                <p>Wisdom Pet Medicine is the only clinic around that will even book pet fish for appointments.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Read more >></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SpiRT. I need to be more careful. Name was the problem. Ought to be bootstrap.min.css